# Why does flutter-test not render a Text widget in the following case?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

I have a widget named `GiftGrid` that shows a placeholder `Text` widget when it receives no items, but the test that checks for the specific case fails, even though it works fine in the app:

```dart
testWidgets('Null list shows placeholder', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [MyLocalizationsDelegate()],
        home: GiftGrid(null)));
    var a = tester.allWidgets.toList();
    expect(find.text("PROPER_QUADRUPLE_CHECKED_STRING"), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

where `GiftGrid` is defined as follows:

```dart
return (widget.giftList?.isEmpty ?? true)
        ? Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(MyLocalizations.of(context).stringThatTranslatesToSameAsTest),
            ),
          ) : StaggeredGridBuilder(...);
```

The debugger shows the contents of a as follows (sorry for the screenshot, I couldn't find a better way to show it):
[image: Contents of a as defined in test case]

EDIT: GifGrid receives a List as the parameter and the following test passes:

```dart
  testWidgets('Gift shows thumbnail if available', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    var gift = GiftModel()
      ..images = [
        "OTHER_IMG_LINK"
      ]
      ..thumbnail =
          "IMG_LINK";

    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: GiftGrid([gift]),
    ));

    expect(find.byWidgetPredicate((widget) {
      return widget is TransitionToImage &&
          (widget.image as AdvancedNetworkImage).url ==
              "IMG_LINK";
    }), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

Comment: You've given part of the definition of `GiftGrid`, but what are its arguments?  Have you tried whittling down the code to a [minimal, complete, verifiable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  When you say that it works "fine in the app", do you mean by running `flutter run test/your_test_file.dart`? If not, I suggest trying that first to observe your test.

Comment: Sorry for the omission. I have added the test case that passes to the question.

Comment: Also, when I meant that it was running fine in the app, I meant using it in my actual app - when I give it `null`, the placeholder text shows up properly. Running `flutter run test/your_test_file.dart` leads to the same error as running the test separately (namely, that no `Text` element was found).

Comment: I meant your definition of `GiftGrid` is incomplete.  You pass `null` to it, but there's no way for us to know what that means.